# could not clear background image to show background color instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fabricjs

I am trying to create an application where user can add text over image or background color. Everything is working properly but when image is in canvas and i want to change image to background color, i could not clear the background image so that i can show background color and text over it.

This is what i am expecting, http://jsbin.com/sukuvoqahi/edit?js,output, which i could do using vanilla javascript but not with reactjs

Here is my reactjs code

```
class ImageBoard extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      canvas: undefined,
      selected: undefined,
      textVisible: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.canvasEl);
    canvas.on("object:selected", e => this.setState({ selected: e.target }));
    canvas.on("selection:cleared", e => this.setState({ selected: undefined }));
    this.setState({ canvas: canvas });
    this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage.selectedImage, canvas);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.getSelectedColor.hex) {
      this.setCanvasBackgroundColor(
        nextProps.getSelectedColor.hex,
        this.state.canvas
      );
    }
    if (nextProps.getSelectedImage.selectedImage) {
      this.setCanvasBackground(
        nextProps.getSelectedImage.selectedImage,
        this.state.canvas
      );
    }
  }

  setCanvasBackground = (image, canvas) => {
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(image, e => {
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
  };

  setCanvasBackgroundColor = (color, canvas) => {
    canvas.backgroundImage = 0;
    const rgbColor = new fabric.Color(color).toRgb();
    canvas.setBackgroundColor(rgbColor.toString(), () => canvas.renderAll());
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="image-board">
              <canvas
                id="canvas"
                ref={el => {
                  this.canvasEl = el;
                }}
                width={500}
                height={400}
                className="z-depth-1"
              />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    getSelectedImage: state.getSelectedImage,
    getSelectedColor: state.getSelectedColor
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ImageBoard);
```

Comment: You should be using `ref` to update your canvas, not what you have saved in `this.state`.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda First of all thanks for your reply. You mean to say, `this.canvasEl.on("object:selected", e => this.setState({ selected: e.target }));` `this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage.selectedImage, this.canvasEl);`